# How to pass values across test cases in NUnit 2.6.2?

Tags: nunit

I am having two Methods in Unit Test case where First Insert Records into Database and Second retrieves back data. I want that input parameter for retrieve data should be the id generated into first method.

```
private int savedrecordid =0;
private object[] SavedRecordId{ get { return new object[] { new object[] { savedrecordid  } }; } }


[Test]
public void InsertInfo()
{
    Info oInfo = new Info();
    oInfo.Desc ="Some Description here !!!";
    savedrecordid  = InsertInfoToDb(oInfo);
}

[Test]
[TestCaseSource("SavedRecordId")]
public void GetInfo(int savedId)
{
    Info oInfo  = GetInfoFromDb(savedId);
}
```

I know each test case executed separately and separate instance we can't share variables across test methods.

Please let me know if there is way to share parameters across the test cases.

Comment: have you tried `public string myProp {get;set;}` i have found that if i set up a Construtor to set up what ever data i need and populate a few getters and setters that does the job for me.

Comment: Yes I did tried with creating property didn't workout :(

Answer (score 5):

The situation you describe is one of unit tests' antipatterns: unit tests should be independent and should not depend on the sequence in which they run.  You can find more at the [xUnit Patterns web site](http://xunitpatterns.com):

- [Unit test should be implemented using *Fresh Fixture*](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fresh%20Fixture.html)
- [Anti pattern *Shared Fixture*](http://xunitpatterns.com/Shared%20Fixture.html)

And both your unit tests have no asserts, so they can't prove whether they are passing or not.

Also they are depend on a database, i.e. external resource, and thus they are not unit but integration tests.

So my advice is to rewrite them:

- Use [mock object](http://xunitpatterns.com/Mock%20Object.html) to decouple from database
- `InsertInfo` should insert info and verify using the mock that an appropriate *insert* call with arguments has been performed
- `GetInfo` should operate with a mock that returns a fake `record` and verify that it works fine

## Example

Notes:
* I have to separate B/L from database operations…
* … and make some assumptions about your solution

```
// Repository incapsulates work with Database
public abstract class Repository<T>
    where T : class
{
    public abstract void Save(T entity);
    public abstract IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
}

// Class under Test
public class SomeRule
{
    private readonly Repository<Info> repository;

    public SomeRule(Repository<Info> repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public int InsertInfoToDb(Info oInfo)
    {
        repository.Save(oInfo);

        return oInfo.Id;
    }

    public Info GetInfoFromDb(int id)
    {
        return repository.GetAll().Single(info => info.Id == id);
    }
}

// Actual unittests
[Test]
public void SomeRule_InsertInfo_WasInserted() // ex. InsertInfo
{
    // Arrange
    Info oInfo = new Info();
    oInfo.Desc = "Some Description here !!!";

    var repositoryMock = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<Repository<Info>>();

    repositoryMock.Expect(m => m.Save(Arg<Info>.Is.NotNull));

    // Act
    var savedrecordid  = new SomeRule(repositoryMock).InsertInfoToDb(oInfo);

    // Assert
    repositoryMock.VerifyAllExpectations();
}

[Test]
public void SomeRule_GetInfo_ReciveCorrectInfo() // ex. GetInfo
{
    // Arrange
    var expectedId = 1;
    var expectedInfo = new Info { Id = expectedId, Desc = "Something" };

    var repositoryMock = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<Repository<Info>>();

    repositoryMock.Expect(m => m.GetAll()).Return(new [] { expectedInfo }.AsEnumerable());

    // Act 
    Info receivedInfo  = new SomeRule(repositoryMock).GetInfoFromDb(expectedId);

    // Assert
    repositoryMock.VerifyAllExpectations();

    Assert.That(receivedInfo, Is.Not.Null.And.SameAs(expectedInfo));
}
```

ps: full example availabel [here](https://gist.github.com/4318084)

Comment: Thanks Akim and Joe I am not sure the patterns like Shared Fixture are supported by nUnit 2.6.2.  Yes I am going to update the test cases with Mock objects and going to decouple from direct database. there will separate use cases for validating database procedures and query.  Yes  in typical scenario the test cases has to independent. Here I am looking for entire user story should be tested. if you can provide link or references for NUnit 2.6 with Shared Fixture and best practices will be very helpful.  Again tanks for response.

Comment: _Shared Fixture_ is an antipatter! Thus you have to avoid implementing it :)
See answer update