# RhinoMock.BackToRecord doesn't seem to work for Exceptions

Tags: nunit, rhino-mocks

I have used the following successfully to reset expectations between tests:

```
MyMock.BackToRecord(BackToRecordOptions.Expectations);
MyMock.Replay();
```

However, in the case where the second test tries to throw an exception on the mocked method, this doesn't seem to work:

```
[SetUp]    
public void Setup()
{
        //reset expectations for each test
        MockRestQuestionClient.BackToRecord(BackToRecordOptions.Expectations);
        MockRestQuestionClient.Replay();
}

[Test]
public void Test1() {
    MyMock.Expect(t => t.Something()).Returns(someObject);
}

[Test]
public void Test2() {
    //this works when run individually, but fails if run after Test1
    MyMock.Expect(t => t.Something()).Throw(new Exception());
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're using the same mocks for different test cases.
Do you have any specific reason to share mocks between tests?

I assume your issue should disappear if you instantiate new mock objects per each test (in `Setup()` method.

**UPDATE**
Please read good comment for sharing data between tests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856246/how-to-pass-values-across-test-cases-in-nunit-2-6-2/13857538#13857538).

**UPDATE2**
If you use base class to set up mocks then I'd suggest to have particular method in base class which does set up (e.g. `Init()`). This method should be marked with attribute `[SetUp]`.
As result `Init()` will be run before each test. And fresh mocks will be used in each test. So you won't need to reset existing mocks.

Comment: Seems like good code re-use to me.  We have a base test classes that sets up all the mocks for use by all the related tests (this has worked fine w/Moq, but Moq lacks a couple features).  And this has also worked fine with RhinoMocks in all but this particular case.

Comment: That's Ok to re-use *the code which sets up all the mocks* in multiple tests. But that's not Ok to re-use *the same mock instances* in multiple tests. See my suggestion how to do that in answer's update.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer with reservations.  I don't feel like there's a compelling argument either way.  The argument for not re-using mocks because the mocks don't work as (I think) they should is not a compelling basis to say how something "should" be done. Mocks should be re-settable, imo, and in fact, they are except in this odd condition.  So, my original question remains unanswered, and perhaps only Ayende can answer it.